# plt.plot TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I want to implement the butterworthfilter with python in jupyter Notebook. Python is new to me and i dont know why i get a error. I search here but i didnt find a solution.

The data are from a CSV-File, it calls Samples.csv

The Data in Samples.csv are like

```
998,4778415
1009,209592
1006,619094
1001,785406
993,9426543
990,1408991
992,736118
995,8127334
1002,381664
1006,094429
1000,634799
999,3287747
1002,318812
999,3287747
1004,427698
1008,516733
1007,964781
1002,680906
1000,14449
994,257009
```

The column calls `Euclidian Norm`. The range of the data are from 0 to 1679.286158 and theyre are 1838 rows.

I wrote this code, it was from a tutorial.

```
from scipy.signal import filtfilt
from scipy import stats

import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

def plot():
    data=pd.read_csv('Samples.csv',sep=";")
    sensor_data=data[['Euclidian Norm']]
    sensor_data=np.array(sensor_data)
    
    time=np.linspace(0,1679.286158,1838)
    plt.plot(time, sensor_data)
    plot.show()
plot()
```

I get the error  `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`and the line of `plt.plot(time, sensor_data)` it marks yellow.

I dont know what is wrong, because i dont see a type failure in the code, does anyone know what could be wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `,` as the decimal separator in your CSV file but you haven't told Pandas that you are doing that.

Try replacing the line

```py
    data=pd.read_csv('Samples.csv',sep=";")
```

with

```py
    data=pd.read_csv('Samples.csv',sep=";", decimal=",")
```

Comment: Thanks it helps! So the decimal operator `.` is default? But i have an another problem i have an error ` AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'show'` and `plot.show()` and `plot()` marks yellow.

Comment: @Nando94: replace `plot.show()` with `plt.show()`.